# React native detect IOS status bar height when calling / sharing hotspot?

Tags: react-native-ios

Status bar height changes when calling or sharing personal hotspot on ios and overlaps view, how to detect status bar height when it changes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've faced this challenge and haven't found answers on stackoverflow / github issues.

I've come up with my own solution, and post it so this can save some time for others.

```
import { NativeModules, StatusBarIOS } from 'react-native'
const { StatusBarManager } = NativeModules

componentDidMount () {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    StatusBarManager.getHeight(response =>
        this.setState({statusBarHeight: response.height})
    )

    this.listener = StatusBarIOS.addListener('statusBarFrameWillChange',
      (statusBarData) =>
        this.setState({statusBarHeight: statusBarData.frame.height})
    )
  }
}

componentWillUnmount () {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && this.listener) {
    this.listener.remove()
  }
}
```

How it works

1) get initial height, note it's async method

```
StatusBarManager.getHeight(response =>
    this.setState({statusBarHeight: response.height}))
```

2) setup listener for status bar change

```
StatusBarIOS.addListener('statusBarFrameWillChange',
    (statusBarData) =>
      this.setState({statusBarHeight: statusBarData.frame.height})
  )
```

3) remove listener in componentWillUnmount

```
if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && this.listener) {
  this.listener.remove()
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful. However, I had to call `StatusBarManager.getHeight(response => this.setState({statusBarHeight: response.height}))` in response to `statusBarFrameWillChange`, as `statusBarData.frame.height` returned the *previous* height on orientation change.

Comment: In 2020 StatusBarIOS is deprecated, use NativeEventEmitter instead.

Comment: This was very helpful. I used it to make a hook. Here's the gist https://gist.github.com/brayhoward/82ed6a68ed2c3727a67cd6e0863d6a1c

Answer (score 6):

You can use [react-native-status-bar-height](https://github.com/ovr/react-native-status-bar-height) library to get height of status bar, and can use like

`marginTop: getStatusBarHeight()`

or you can use as a height of StatusBar, if its set to translucent.

**If you are using Expo**

then just `import { Constants } from 'expo'`

and height will be `Constants.statusBarHeight`

[See Ref Here](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/899#issuecomment-362123402) and [here for Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants#expoconstantsstatusbarheight)

Answer (score 2):

Now it's `import Constants from 'expo-constants';`

Change `'expo'` to `'expo-constants'`.